# How can Excel search for value in a column, copy different cell in same row and paste in a separate workbook?

Tags: excel-formula

how can i log the "total" cell of all the "fails" in a different workbook?

```
Book1
1st num 2nd num total   T/F
5       5       10      TRUE
6       6       3       FALSE
7       7       14      TRUE
8       8       4       FALSE

Book2
total
3
4
```

for example, in a different workbook i want A:1 to have value 3 and A:2 to have value 4 because both were false and all other values were true. how can i do this? I don't want spaces between each number or have to manually filter or remove spaces.

the true/false is a drop down menu, has a key sheet. i am not sure if that affects the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need a little tweaking but I hope it helps.

```
Sub Copy()

  Dim wbDest As Workbook
  Dim wsDest As Worksheet
  Dim wsSource As Worksheet
  Dim iTFCol As Integer
  Dim iLastRow As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim iDestRow As Integer
  Dim iDestCol As Integer
  Dim iValueCol As Integer

  Set wbDest = Workbooks("Destination.xlsx")
  Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
  Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Destination")

  iDestCol = 1
  iTFCol = 4
  iValueCol = 3
  iLastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iTFCol).End(xlUp).Row


  For i = 1 To iLastRow
    If wsSource.Cells(i, iTFCol).Value = False Then
      iDestRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, iDestCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      wsDest.Cells(iDestRow, iDestCol).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, iValueCol).Value
    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```